# Can Attribute reference in python be compared with static class in Java ?

Tags: java, python, oop

I am assuming that Attribute reference is kind of similar to static class in Java.

For example: I have declared a class

```
>>> class Square:
        def __init__(self):
                self.side=0
        def area(self):
                print(self.side*self.side)
```

Then this line works fine:

```
>>> Square.side=2
```

But getting the error while accessing the 'area' method

```
>>> Square.area()
```

Could someone explain how actually attribute reference in python works? 
And clarify my assuming is correct or not as well?

Comment: You're setting a new attribute on the class (not on the instance) in the first case

Comment: Assigning to a *class attribute* is like creating a static *variable* in Java. There really are no "static classes" in Python, and no real need for them. Static classes really only make sense in a language like Java, which forces you to write class definitions for *everything*. In Python, you would just use a module with funcitons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use static mehtods in python, but not that way. Think about semantics also, not only rough syntax.

`Square` is a describer for every possible square. Would it make any sense to say `square.size = 3`? Probably not, because then we limit the subject to 3-unit sized squares, not every square.

Same goes for `area`. You do not want the area of a "square". You want the area of a specific square - or as called in python, the `instance`. Therefore, your program will make a lot more by assigning an instance of a `Square` to a variable, and using that variable to calculate the area:

```
>>> s = Square()

>>> s.side = 1
>>> s.area()
1
>>> s.side = 3
>>> s.area()
9
```

Comment: So, attribute reference in java is not similar compared to static class ??

Answer (score 0):

To access area method ,you need to create Square object as it is instance method.

```
square_object=Square()
square_object.side=2
square_object.area() 
#prints 4
```

For more information on classes,instance methods,class methods refer

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html